# Adicionar uma coluna 'Virtual' em um SELECT no Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Gostaria de colocar uma coluna temporária que só fosse gerada na consulta que vai ser vinculada ao `CD_NIVEL` digamos: "Se `CD_NIVEL = 5` cria uma coluna  `'Exclui'` como se fosse uma descrição do que significa o 5, procurei aqui e não encontrei nada sou novo e estou aprendendo SQL.

Código SQL:

```
   select  a.cd_usuario
,       (select nm_usuario from adm_usuario where cd_usuario=a.cd_usuario and cd_empresa=a.cd_empresa) as ds_usuario 
,       (select cd_funcionario from adm_usuario where cd_usuario=a.cd_usuario and cd_empresa=a.cd_empresa) as ds_funcionario
,       a.cd_empresa
,       a.cd_componente
,       a.cd_nivel
from ADM_USUCMPEMP a
where cd_nivel=5 
and (select tp_privilegio from adm_usuario where cd_usuario=a.cd_usuario and cd_empresa=a.cd_empresa)='1' 
and (select tp_bloqueio from adm_usuario where cd_usuario=a.cd_usuario and cd_empresa=a.cd_empresa)=0 
--and a.cd_usuario=6029 
and a.cd_empresa=90 
--and a.cd_componente like '%FISR031%'
order by 5
```

[image: Resultado do SELECT]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o `CASE` para conseguir isso no seu select. [Exemplo nesse link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/94578/2/0).

```
SELECT 
    a.cd_usuario,
    ...
    a.cd_nivel, 
    CASE
        WHEN a.cd_nivel = 5
        THEN 'Exclui'
    END AS DescNivel
FROM
    ...
```

Lembrando que os outros valores terão valor `null` nessa coluna.

Comment: E o perguntador some.